# Overwrite phtml file from adminthml issue

Tags: blocks, template, magento-1, overrides

How should I overwrite this phtml file tabs.phtml, in my custom module? This file is located in:

`app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/tabs.phtml`

is loaded from core from this class `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tabs` in the constructor:

```
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->setTemplate('widget/tabs.phtml');
    }
```

UPDATE:

```
<global>
        <blocks>
            <mynamespace_mymodule>
                <class>Mynamespace_Mymodule_Block</class>
            </mynamespace_mymodule>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                    <widget_tabs>Mynamespace_Mymodule_Block_Adminhtml_Widget_Tabs</widget_tabs>
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
        </blocks>
```

Answer (score 1):

**it's impossible to rewrite (in the Magento sense) classes that are used as superclasses.**

for other's Rewrite the block

```
<adminhtml>
    <rewrite>
      <dashboard_totals>Spacename_Modulename_Block_Adminhtml_Dashboard_Totals</dashboard_totals>
    </rewrite>
</adminhtml>
```

and block will be

```
<?php
class Spacename_Modulename_Block_Adminhtml_Dashboard_Totals extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Dashboard_Totals 
{
     protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->setTemplate('modulename/test/totals.phtml');
    }

}
```

Comment: Thx for your reply. I update my post. If i do a die() in my constructor, it is completly ignored. Maybe there is smth else. Can you check my post again ?

Comment: and it is Block_Adminhtml_Widget_Tabs  not Block_Adminhtml_Review_Widget_Tabs , you added the "Review"

Comment: @Chester after lot of search if find **it's impossible to rewrite (in the Magento sense) classes that are used as superclasses**